# <bean:write> tag for limiting the size of returned string

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl

I am using following tag for showing comments on jsp, now I want to show only first 10 character of comments...

Example: "This is very urgent please provide details"
Then `<bean:write>` should write only "This is ver......"

is there any way to achieve it, 
    `<bean:write name="order" property="ordercomments"  />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily do that using the JSTL fn:substring function, combined with the `c:out` tag to make sure propert HTML escaping is done :

```
<c:out value="${fn:substring(someBean.someProperty, 0, 10)}" />
```

See http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html for a tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Not using the `<bean:write>` tag (which in general, you shouldn't be using anyway--when JSTL functionality overlaps with Struts 1 tags, use the JSTL tag).

This kind of functionality is usually wrapped up in a custom tag, though, to allow variable lengths, add the ellipses (…) character only when necessary, break on a word boundry (don't want to say "I like your tit…" when the phrase is "I like your title suggestion"), etc.

This could be wrapped up easily in a JSP-based tag using the built-in JSP EL functionality as JB mentions, or is pretty quick to implement using a variety of other means.